# iOS CoreBluetooth - Peripheral connect to Central within range

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

I have a basic BLE App that I am running with Objective-C.  I am using PeripheralManager and running my iPhone8 as a peripheral with serivces, characteristics added.

What I would like to do is connect to a central device that I know by Device ID or when it comes within range.

I have written a BLE App for Android that does this now.  All I have to do is trigger the device.connectGatt()  when onConnectionStateChange() is connected. This is in the BluetoothGattServerCallback() eventHandler.

What is the equivant for this in iOS?  Keep in mind I that this is at connected state, not when the central has subscribed for services.  This seems obvious in BluetoothGatt on Android but not see anything obvious in iOS PeriphalManager.

Anyone done anything similar? Seems to be a basic question, please help.

Answer (score 1):

In CoreBluetooth it is the central that makes the connection.

If you know the device-specific identifier for a peripheral (ie, you have previously discovered it on this central device) then you can attempt to retrieve a `CBPeripheral` instance from the central and then issue a `connect`. This will complete when the device comes into range. If you allow background mode then this connect can be completed when your app is in the background.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  

Im aware that its the central that initiates the connection. But the issue is I cant change the code for the Central. Its already configured and running to look for Advertisements with a certain Service UUID.    It then tries to connect and make a WriteRequest to the Descriptor for Notify (2902).

I am not seeing the connection attempt made so I am seeing there is a way the Peripheral could initiate the connect request when the Central is in range.

Do you happen to have any solid code references for this?  Obj-C or Swift.

Comment: The official reference is the Core Bluetooth framework documentation and the Core Bluetooth programming guide from Apple. `CBPeripheralManager` can only respond to connection requests, it cannot initiate connections.