# Can a peripheral request to a central for connection?

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi3

I am fairly new to BLE, recently I have done an experiment where I have made an iOS app which is central, it scan for a particular peripheral and connect to it and finally it writes something to the characteristics to do an action. Link: [Swift-BLE](https://github.com/nthrussell/Swift-BLE) . Now I have got a new project where the **central** would be the iOS app and the **peripheral** would be a **raspberry pi 3 B+** running on Linux. It should have an on off switch for activating BLE link. Once On is should start scanning for ble peripheral devices. When getting a connection request from the Linux peripheral it should display the passcode and connect to it. Next it should sent it a long JSON string and read back a JSON string from the gatt profile.

I don't know how a peripheral request for a connection with the central, and how the central handle it. Any suggestion would be really helpful.

Again, my question is not how to discover, connect peripheral, my question is how can a peripheral send request to central for a connection & how the central process it. Is it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SWIFT - BLE communications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794107/swift-ble-communications)

Comment: how ? Did you got my point ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51995104/4577897

Comment: Nope, its not same. Please have a look again.

Comment: The central device scans for peripherals. Not the other way around.
EDIT: Here is a good [resource](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothOverview/CoreBluetoothOverview.html).

Comment: Now thats the point I was looking for, thank you.